# user control inside dynamic user control click event not firing?

Tags: c#

I have a page where there is a div, for which the user controls are added dynamically through the code using the LoadControl of user control.

The user control contains another user control (lets say ChildUC).
The ChildUC contains a gridview which has Insert and Delete buttons.

The problem is, even though I click on these buttons, the click event is not getting fired nor the gridview command event.
The page is being postbacked and just exits after the page load, it is not firing any other events.

I am debugging this for last few days so far, but of no luck.

Please do help me. Thanks in Advance.

Code:

```
 <div id="dvMain" runat="server">
  </div>

   private void CreateHeaders()
    {

        foreach (Header hd in HeaderCollection)
        {
            List<Question> lstQuestion = QuestionCollection.FindAll(p => p.HID.Equals(hd.HeaderID));
            Sales_UserControls_Questions Question = null;
            if (lstQuestion.Count > 0)
            {
                Question = (Sales_UserControls_Questions)LoadControl("~/Sales/UserControls/Questions.ascx"); // This is the main user control that is being loaded dynamically
                Question.ID = "Question"+hd.HID;
                Question.lstQuestions = lstQuestion;
            }
            dvMain.Controls.Add(Header);
            if (HQQuestion != null)
                dvMain.Controls.Add(Question); // user control being added to div

        }
    }

    //Questions.ascx

<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="grdContent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        OnRowDataBound="grdContent_RowDataBound" EnableTheming="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnQuestionID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("QID") %>' />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnQuestionType" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("QTP") %>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionID" runat="server" EnableTheming="False" Text='<%# Eval("QID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSHR" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <div>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpnlDGV" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <DG:View ID="ucDGView" runat="server"></DG:View>
                           </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
//end of questions.ascx

//ucDGView.ascx
<div>
     <asp:GridView ID="grdDGView" runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="grdDGView_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="grdDGView_RowDeleting"
                OnRowCreated="grdDGView_RowCreated" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" OnRowCommand="grdDGView_RowCommand">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <dl id="dvNT" runat="server">
                                            <dt>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblNT" runat="server" Text="NT:"></asp:Label>
                                            </dt>
                                            <dd>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNM" runat="server">
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                            </dd>
                                        </dl>
                                        <dl id="dvOSD" runat="server" class="grid_6 alpha MT10" visible="false">
                                            <dt>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblOSDT" runat="server" Text="OSDT:"></asp:Label>
                                            </dt>
                                            <dd>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOSDT" runat="server" MaxLength="10" CssClass="maskDate"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtOSDTE" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtOSDT"
                                                    Enabled="True" Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
                                                </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                            </dd>
                                        </dl>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Sales/Common/Images/delete_red_mini.jpg"
                                CausesValidation="false" CssClass="cancel" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OID")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnAdd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Sales/Common/Images/PLUS_MINI.png"
                                CausesValidation="false" CssClass="cancel" CommandName="Add" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QID")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
//end of ucDGView.ascx
```

Comment: hard to tell for sure but if it is posting back instead of firing the event, try wrapping the code in  if(!IsPostBack) { your code    }   OFten i've had cases where the code posts back when I'm wanting it to do something first and as a result it is like a fresh load of the page.

Comment: Brain Thanks a bunch for your reply, but it is already in postback.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand here is where in the [asp.net page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) does it receive the event from the frontend.

The event that triggers the postback is sent back to asp.net is a hidden form element called the event target.

This input is processed in in a function called the `ProcessPostData`. 
If your control is not present in the controls collection by then, it cannot receive the event. So you get a postback, but no event handlers are fired.

That means, if you want your event handlers to fire, you must create all your controls before the load event. It seems you have to decide which controls to load depending upon some user input. User inputs are not available on `Init`. You can override the `LoadViewState` method, and process your user input there.

[image: Page life cycle]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I understand the concept, but I have like 100 controls on the page, which needs to be loaded on Init, it makes the page unresponsive. so, please do let me know if there is any other solution.

Comment: No matter where in the page life cycle you add them, it is going to take the same amount of processing time. I guess you are not adding all 100 of them every time. The decision of which controls to add depends on which were added when the page was rendered. Saving this decision in the `ViewState` help to add only those controls back on  the next Postback

Comment: no because all these user controls are added dynamically, I am not getting handle of those.