# Get GridView in Multiple UserControl from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, code-behind

**IpInterfaceUC UserControl:**

```
<div id="dvChannel" runat="server" style="height: 205px; width: 550px; overflow: auto;
        margin-left: 5px;">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvChannelUC">
</div>
```

**CodeBehind for Init**

```
int indexInterface=0;
foreach (DataRow row in dtDevicesListByRole.Rows)
{
                    ctrIpInterfaceUC = (Test2.SetupGroup.Ipservice.IpInterfaceUC)LoadControl("IpInterfaceUC.ascx");
                    Control ctr = (Control)ctrIpInterfaceUC;
                    ctr.ID = "device_"+ip+"_"+port+"$"+indexInterface;
                    phDevices.Controls.Add(ctr);//PlaceHolder for add many UserControl
}
```

**Html Show**

```
<div id="dvChannel">
<div id="device_192.168.2.19_3331_0_pnlChannelUC">
  <div id="device_192.168.2.19_3331_0_dvChannel">
    <table id="device_192.168.2.19_3331_0_gvChannelUC">
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="dvChannel">
<div id="device_192.168.2.19_3331_1_pnlChannelUC">
  <div id="device_192.168.2.19_3331_1_dvChannel">
    <table id="device_192.168.2.19_3331_1_gvChannelUC">
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Question**
How do I get gridview from multiple UserControl?

Answer (score 1):

Expose the gridview through a public property on your UserControl:

```
public GridView Grid
{
  get { return gvChannelUC; }
}
```

Then

```
List<string, string> Grids = new List<string, string>(); // <UCId, GridId>
...
ctrIpInterfaceUC = (Test2.SetupGroup.Ipservice.IpInterfaceUC)LoadControl("IpInterfaceUC.ascx");
string Id = "device_"+ip+"_"+port+"$"+indexInterface;

GridView ctrGridView = ctrIpInterfaceUC.Grid;
Grids.Add(Id, ctrGridView.ClientID);

Control ctr = (Control)ctrIpInterfaceUC;
ctr.ID = Id
phDevices.Controls.Add(ctr);//PlaceHolder for add many UserControl
...
```

Comment: Your suggestion is useful.Thanks so much.I have another issues,May we disccuss about it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189851/cant-access-gridview-event-at-usercontrol-by-codebehind/14190246#comment19706841_14190246

Comment: I assume in the other question you are referring to this same block of code? You should add the event handler to the control in the same section that you access the Grid property. 

i.e. `ctrIpInterfaceUC.RaiseSelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(OnRaiseSelectedIndexChanged);`

If you use the double tab trick it will stub out the method for you.

Comment: Individual UserControl has a ID,So that,I register Event to seperate UserControl.Didn't refer to same block of code.

Comment: Your idea mean that I just add a event to a UserControl.Can't add event to next UserControl?

Comment: May we move to a discussion by chat on stackover?I wondered if you discuss with me about this issues

Answer (score 0):

While you can recursively use FindControl to find it, a much better approach is to let the UserControl `IpInterfaceUC` decide how to bind data to the controls within it.

You could add a public method `ShowData` to you UserControl and pass the data to be displayed to it. It can then assign it to `gvChannelUC`.

```
int indexInterface=0;
foreach (DataRow row in dtDevicesListByRole.Rows)
{
    var ctrIpInterfaceUC = (Test2.SetupGroup.Ipservice.IpInterfaceUC)LoadControl("IpInterfaceUC.ascx");
    ctrIpInterfaceUC.ShowData(myRows);
    ctrIpInterfaceUC.ID = "device_"+ip+"_"+port+"$"+indexInterface;
    phDevices.Controls.Add(ctrIpInterfaceUC);//PlaceHolder for add many UserControl
}
```

Comment: I tried:
**GridView gvChannelUC = (GridView)FindControl("device_192.168.2.19_3331_0_gvChannelUC");**;But gvChannelUC is null.

Comment: That won't work. You will have to search recursively in the controls collection of `ctrIpInterfaceUC`. I would highly encourage calling a method within your UserControl though

Comment: I know your idea,While I tried it,Will we disccus something.Bcoz I use dynamic usercontrol,So that,We can't use ctrIPinterfaceUC.getGridView();.It'll not get individual GridView of a UserControl.I've been trying recursively find control function.Result soon.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic usercontrol"? Even if you use LoadControl, it is type casted to your user control class. This allows you to call any public methods of that class

Comment: Nice to meet you,nunespascal.Thanks you in advance.I need discuss with you something for clearly.;).Ah,"Dynamic usercontrol" which I mean that when we use "foreach (DataRow row in dtDevicesListByRole.Rows)" , we just add many usercontrol to placeholder,And don't care about these control.So that,We will get difficult for get Grid propertities on usercontrol.Yep?

Comment: It worked fine now.May we disscuss about another issues.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189851/cant-access-gridview-event-at-usercontrol-by-codebehind/14190246#comment19706841_14190246.Thanks

Comment: It didn't work when I press SelectIndexCchanged at these Gridview

Comment: In which event did you add it? To receive events, controls should be added before `ProcessPostData` in the page life cycle.

Comment: hey brother,I add it at PageLoad

Comment: Too late. Refer the page life cycle `ProcessPostData` is called just after `LoadViewState`

Comment: When i add it at PageLoad().It debug to main page (aspx page),It didn't debug at UserControl page (ascx page).So that,Gridview can't show selectIndex Row.

Comment: May you access my machine by teamviewer or webex for some advice.yes?.Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, but that is not possible. Firewalls here will block that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23082/discussion-between-binh-tieu-and-nunespascal)

Comment: :-( blocked too. Take a look at these answers i have given earlier. I believe you are facing the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834369/user-control-inside-dynamic-user-control-click-event-not-firing/11834955#11834955   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752203/dynamic-controls-associated-events-dont-fire-if-recreated-during-page-load/11752521#11752521

Comment: So,If we want to fire event after click dynamic usercontrol.We'll set it which was not add at pageload()

Comment: We should be try it with Page_PreLoad() or Page_Init()?

Comment: Controls added in Page_Load cannot receive events. They don't exist when events are processed

Comment: I tried create dynamic usercontrol in protected void Page_Init() and 
LoadViewState(object savedState){
            base.LoadViewState(savedState);
            CreateControls();
        }.But it didn't fire debug at selectIndex event in UserControl.

Comment: I refactored my code.It worked fine when I wrote it in PageLoad()

Comment: Because I set Id of UserControl is 'device_abc$0'.So that,It didn't recognized when I fire event.I set id to 'device_abc__0',It work fine when I press event.

Comment: My scenario is when I selectIndex at GridView,It must to rewrite all of web.So that,It's very very slowly.Do you have any solution for it?

Comment: P/s: In main page,PageLoad(){ for(){register dynamic usercontrol}}

Comment: P/s: In UserControl page, PageLoad(){ getValue from database for fill into GridView}