# Can't access GridView event at usercontrol by codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, code-behind, webusercontrol

**IpInterfaceUC UserControl**

```
<div id="dvChannel" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvChannelUC" 
            OnRowCommand="gvChannelUC_RowCommand"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvChannel_SelectedIndexChanged"
        />
</div>
```

**IPServices page CodeBehind**

```
if (!IsPostBack){
}else
{    
 string str_btn = Request.Form.Keys[Request.Form.Keys.Count - 1].ToString();
 handleClick(str_btn);
}
```

**Question**

It always show **str_btn** is null.If I click Button,It'll show button's id.But when I click Select at GridView,It show **str_btn** is null.It should be show GridView's id when we click select.

Thanks for any explain.

Comment: As per my understanding you need grid event handing (.ascx) on  page/codebehind (.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `name` attribute to your gridview,ie `name="yourGridName"`.

```
<div id="dvChannel" runat="server" name="yourGridName">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvChannelUC" name="yourGridName"
            OnRowCommand="gvChannelUC_RowCommand"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvChannel_SelectedIndexChanged"
        />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any solution,brother.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need grid event handing (.ascx) on  page/codebehind (.aspx).

declare eventhandler in userControl

```
 public event EventHandler<EventArgs>  RaiseSelectedIndexChanged=delegate {};
```

handle userControl selectedindexchanged event in userControl.cs

```
   protected void gvChannel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var raiseSelectedIndexChanged = RaiseSelectedIndexChanged ;
        if(raiseSelectedIndexChanged!=null)
        {
            raiseSelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

register and use your userControl in aspx (which I hope you already did) this code will go in aspx page

```
        <uc:userControl OnRaiseSelectedIndexChanged="OnRaiseSelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

handle the event in aspx code behind

```
    protected void OnRaiseSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //handle your event and put logic 
    }
```

I hope i make it clear , let me know if it confuses you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.;).I have some question.Hoping you'll help me figure out of it.Thanks.**var raiseSelectedIndexChanged = RaiseSelectedIndexChanged **.Because It was used at codebehind.May you rewrite this code.I think it will not work at codebehind.;)

Comment: I did not get you , please tell me what is not working or post your sample code  so that I can modify it.

Comment: var raiseSelectedIndexChanged = RaiseSelectedIndexChanged;  It didnt' work

Comment: is it giving compilation error ? I am using .net 4.0 , so var is allowed. try this EventHandler<EventArgs> raiseSelectedIndexChanged = RaiseSelectedIndexChanged ;

Comment: It work fine.But I used event at dynamic control.So that,I can't use <uc:userControl OnRaiseSelectedIndexChanged="OnRaiseSelectedIndexChanged"/>.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150848/get-gridview-in-multiple-usercontrol-from-codebehind/14150889#comment19599867_14150889. Do you have any solution.Thanks

Comment: ctrIpInterfaceUC.RaiseSelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(OnRaiseSelectedIndexChanged);

Comment: My Scenario is that have 2 usercontrol.So that,At individual usercontrol,I register OnRaiseSelectedIndexChanged function for it.But it didn't run this function (I debug by VS2008)

Comment: Do you have any solution,brother.I can share teamviewer's id for your help.Thanks

Comment: please send you code at paritoshmmmec@gmail.com, I will see what i can do to help you to accomplish your task , I will be availble after 10 PM

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22369/discussion-between-binh-tieu-and-paritosh)